# Links not working upon loading page for the first time

Tags: support, bug

When a page has loaded the first time, sometimes links like edit, add comment, share, flag do not work. I have been having noticing this for quite some time now.

On reloading the page, either refresh or clicking on the post title however, they seem to work.

But then, I noticed this not only while at work but also at home.

- First, I thought it would have something to do with caching of scripts etc. So I even tried clearing my cache.
- And this is not for deleted/closed questions, I verified.
- There are
  no errors in my browser console either.

Although, I know it might not be a well-documented bug because I use only **Chrome (v21.0.1180.79 m)**, I thought it should still be worth posting.

**UPDATE :**

This was the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

in the file `cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=c60de8021771:24`

[image]

I'm guessing something hasn't loaded the first time? Still digging into it.

Comment: I use chrome and do not have that problems.

Comment: I forgot to ask if it's just me or has anybody else also come across this glitch.(*if it even is one*)

Comment: Maybe it's a connection issue and the scripts are not completely loading? Did you check the network tab on chrome tools?

Comment: @bfavaretto: The network tab should already be open for it to show the requests being made. :/

Comment: What version of Chrome?

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby: The latest - 21.0.1180.79 m. Updated answer too.

Comment: [Might be a Chrome bug](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/_4Lg7K9ayl4/9tKi67DhM6QJ).

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby: See my update. I was able to reproduce this.